# Magento 2.3.2 : How to send email to customer after order cancellation by admin?

Tags: magento2.3.2, cancel-orders

I know the cancel order event `order_cancel_after` but how can I send cancelation e-mail to the customer when admin cancels their order from admin.

How to write a custom extension for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: You need to send a custom email to customer. Right?

Comment: @ Dhaduk Mitesh, Yeah you right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an event file in `Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name='order_cancel_after'>
        <observer name='order_cancel_after' instance='Vendor\Module\Observer\CancelOrder'/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Create email template xml in `etc/email_templates.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="cancel_order_template" label="Email Form" file="cancelordertemplate.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Create an email template in `view/frontend/email/cancelordertemplate.html`

```
<!--@subject {{var template_subject}} @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:10px 0 10px 0">
                <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:13px;padding:0 9px 9px 9px;">
                                            <p>{{trans "Dear"}} {{var customername}},</p>
                                            {{var email_content|raw}}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Create an observer file in `Vendor/Module/Observer/CancelOrder.php`

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
    use \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

    class CancelOrder implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function __construct(
            StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
            TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
            LoggerInterface $logLoggerInterface,
            StateInterface $inlineTranslation
        ) {
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
            $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
            $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
            $this->logLoggerInterface = $logLoggerInterface;
        }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            try {
                $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
                $custFirstname = ''; # Set customer name from order
                $custEmail = ''; # Set customer email from order
                $template_sub = ''; # Set email subject
                $sender_name = ''; # Set sender name
                $sender_email = ''; # Set sender email
                $template_content = ''; # Set email content
                $templateId = 'cancel_order_template';
                $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
                $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
                $sendFrom = $sender_email;
                $senderName = $sender_name;
                $sendTo = $custEmail;
                $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => 'frontend',
                            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars([
                        'template_subject' => $template_sub,
                        'customername' => $custFirstname,
                        'email_content' => $template_content,
                    ])
                    ->setFrom(array('email' => $sendFrom, 'name' => $senderName))
                    ->addTo(array($sendTo))
                    ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
                $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

Clear cache: `php bin/magento cache:clean` and check it.

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: I am facing this error See this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/pt6q40
In this Method : ($this->canCancel())
Can you please guide me in this.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Remove that condition.

Comment: Currently I am checking and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: @ DhadukMitesh, Thanks for answer it works for me..!!

Comment: @DhadukMitesh 
I have applied this and it's just show white screen on reload and stop. I have checked $transport = $this->transportBuilder in that part there is some problem .
will you please help.

Comment: @Prits First check the Observer file call or not and add a log on that file. and find from which line execution breaks. also check var/log file.